# Converting unknown amount of strings into variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently working on my computing project which would allow a user to create an indefinite amount of files. What I'm currently stuck on is retrieving these values to let a user select one here is my code:

```
 function DispMonth(){
 $dateList=GetDates($_Session['user']);//use session id
foreach($dateList as $value){//get each value
    echo '<tr>' .$value.'</tr>';}
}
?>
<body>
<table>
    <th><tr> Made Budgets</tr> </th>
    <?php DispMonth(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

My GetDates function is:

```
function GetDates($id){
$result=mysql_query('select monthYear from database where userId='.$_Session['user'].'');
while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $x[]=$row['monthYear'];}
return x;
}
```

Essentially I would like the table to look something like this:

```
|monthYear| edit | delete |
```

With edit and delete being links/buttons which would send the value of monthYear to a new php page to fetch all the values.(Monthyear is a primary key in my sql table)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code which you need to fix, and few changes you need to make to make it work, such as:

- Your table structure is wrong. `<tr>` cannot be inside `<th>`, also the closing `</table>` tag is missing.
- You're fetching rows from the result set using `mysql_fetch_object()` function but accessing the column values using `$row[...]`, which is wrong. Use [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) instead.

  ```
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ...
  ```
- Given the fact that `monthYear` is the primary key of your table, make use of this column value in *edit* and *delele* buttons in your `foreach` loop, like this:

  ```
  <a href="newPage.php?monthYear=<?php echo $value ?>&edit">edit</a>
  <a href="newPage.php?monthYear=<?php echo $value ?>&delete">delete</a>
  ```

  Later, on *newPage.php* page, you can edit or delete any particular row like this:

  ```
  if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
      $monthYear = $_GET['monthYear'];
      // Edit the row
  }

  if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
      $monthYear = $_GET['monthYear'];
      // Delete the row
  }
  ```

So your functions and table structure would be like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Made Budgets</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <?php DispMonth(); ?>
</table>

function DispMonth(){
    $dateList=GetDates($_Session['user']);
    foreach($dateList as $value){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
            <td><a href="newPage.php?monthYear=<?php echo $value ?>&edit">edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="newPage.php?monthYear=<?php echo $value ?>&delete">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}

function GetDates($id){
    $result=mysql_query('select monthYear from database where userId='.$_SESSION['user'].'');
    $x = array();
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $x[] = $row['monthYear'];
    }
    return x;
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Thank you so much & thanks for pointing out the other errors too.